# Scoll and slide Fullpage.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullpage.js

I use Fullpage.js and I want to build a scroll website like this

My html code:

```html
<div class="section" id="section0">
 </div>
 <div class="section" id="section1">
   <div class="slide">1</div>
   <div class="slide">2</div>
   <div class="slide">3</div>
 </div>
<div class="section" id="section2">
 </div>
```

I would like to do something like this:

(start from section 0)
Scroll down : section 1 slide 1 --> section 1 slide 2 --> section 1 slide 3 --> section 2

(start from section 2)
Scroll up: section 1 slide 3 --> section 1 slide 2 --> section 1 slide 1 --> section 0

I roughly got some hint doing using "onLeave" or "onSlideLeave"

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Questions like "Any idea" that can be answered with "Yes" are seldom good questions. Read [help→tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour)) about just questions and no chit-chat, therefore *thanks* should never be part of good post.

Comment: If you want to scroll horizontally by using the mousewheel, then you would have to modify the core of fullPage.js. If you really need it [contact me](http://alvarotrigo.com/#contact-page).

Answer (score 0):

You kinda have to make your own extension of the plugin for this, because moveTo affects only the slider in the section that you are moving, and moveSlideRight() or Left affects the slider in the current section, you can somehow make the slider to be position fixed when it becomes visible and when you scroll, in the back the sections will move but the slider will remain on the screen, here is the tricky part, you have to make your own method witch is triggered onLeave of a section to move the slider

Comment: I added `code`
onLeave : function(index, nextIndex, direction){if(index == 2 && direction == 'down')$.fn.fullpage.moveSlideRight();} `code` but not working also.

Comment: that wont work because $.fn.fullpage.moveSlideRight(); will affect the slider from the active section, so on leave the section where your slide is, is no more the active one. look in the source code on how the moveSlideRight(); works and make your own where you don't have to depend on the section that is active

Comment: if u cant manage to make it, i will give it a try tonight for you, but this will be in like 10 hours,

Comment: could not make it :/ did you find any solutions?